# How can I persist changes to Console.Title past the lifecycle of a process in C#?

Tags: c#, powershell, cmd

Powershell is able to change the Title text of a terminal that outlives the process that sets it.

https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/blob/a8adab23190584668b562954e778169c04364755/src/posh-git.psm1

Is an example of "Posh Git" a Powershell script for git, that shows the status of a git repository in the title bar and prompt when working inside powershell.

At work we have a Console C# app, that I wish to do the same thing (Setting the title window, but having it persist past the app's lifecycle)

It can be run from either PowerShell or cmd.

At the moment I set the title like this:

```
var path = RepositoryHelpers.TryGetContainerRootPath(workingDirectory);
using (var containerRepo = new Repository(path))
{
    Console.Title = $"GitSAFE - {containerRepo.Head.FriendlyName}";
}
```

However, the `Console.Title` property is reset once the process is over.

How can I persist changes to the Console Title using C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you can't persist the change you are asking about.  However you can create a profile script that sets the title every time you launch powershell.  On a windows machine you can create a file at `C:\Users\_your_user_id\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`.  You could put your commands in there.  The down side to this is that every user has to update his profile.  There is also a machine profile that influences startup scripts that you can set through global policy.

One possible mitigation is you could create a script that checks for a startup script that you can configure using windows infrastructure.  Here's a snippet of my profile that does this:

```
Write-Host "Hello From Your Profile: $PsScriptRoot"
$gitDrive = $env:GitDrive
if ($gitDrive -ne "" -and $gitDrive -ne $null) {
  if (Test-Path "$($gitDrive)") {
    Write-Host "Your GitDrive is $($gitDrive)"
  }
  else {
    Write-Host "Your GitDrive is $($GitDrive) but that path does not exist."  -Fore Yellow
    Write-Host "Update the environment variable to point to your enlistment."  -Fore Yellow
    exit
  }

  if (Test-Path "$($gitDrive)AutoStart.PS1") {
    . "$($gitDrive)AutoStart.PS1"
  }
  exit
}
else {
  Write-Host "Add your GitDrive environment variable to your profile."
}
```

As long as you have an environment variable that points to your git repos folder its `AutoStart.ps1` scripts runs at every shell.  YMMV but this `works on my machine`.